# Setup discourse docker on mac os

Tags: macos, docker, discourse

I'm following standard guide to install discourse on my local mac.
After launching the setup tool `./discourse-setup` I've got error message:

```
cd /pups && git pull && /pups/bin/pups --stdin
/usr/local/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: er.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more info.
.
r/discourse/shared/standalone/log/var-log
are not shared from OS X and are not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
```

Initially I've tried to install to my work directory inside /Users. This folder is in File Sharing.

Then I installed to /var/discourse folder, the same error. I assumed that `var` folder is not in Docker File Sharing so I tried to add `/var` folder to Docker's Sharing Files and got message

```
The path /var is reserved by Docker
```

What might be a problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Docker icon in the top of the screen and click on `Preferences` -> `File Sharing` and add an other folder different than /var, eg: `/Applications/htdocs/myproject/` every folder should be dedicated to a project.

[image: screenshot of the dialog box]